# Writing text into entry field in tcl/tk dialog

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

In a tcl/tk dialog I need to get a text input from the user.

```
proc add_entry { command } {
   global TestValue

   entry .dialog_TC.enText -textvariable TestValue
   grid  .dialog_TC.enText -row 1 -column 1 -columnspan 2 -pady 1 -padx 1       
}
```

The problem:
Whenever the user writes a single letter, into the entry-field, the dialog is closed immediately.

Comment: With your example, I don't have the problem you mention. Because you want a dialog, you should maybe use a tk_dialog or a tk_messageBox ?

Comment: That's strange. I just made a new dialog with just a frame and an entry. In the new dialog I also don't have that problem.  When I comment out most of my complete script except for a frame and an entry field, there is also no problem. I suppose, there is a problem with the shortkeys that I implemented, too.

Comment: You only include the code to set things up, not the code to respond to the input. _As written,_ it won't do anything like what you describe (and it lacks anything to use `$command` too…)

Comment: @Donal: Sorry, I didn't put the complete script as it is pretty long. And I didn't think, that the problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: I've written up what I think the problem might be, and yes, the problem is elsewhere. Without seeing lots of code it's hard to say for sure, but I really think it's a `vwait`-on-the-wrong-thing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've got a trace elsewhere on the `TestValue` variable (possibly due to `vwait` or `tkwait variable`) that is detecting the change to the variable and `destroy`ing the widget when that happens, possibly by killing the whole dialog. You don't include the code, but it's probably something like:

```
proc make-me-a-dialog {} {
    toplevel .dialog_TC
    # ...
    add_entry { something ... }
    # ...
    vwait TestValue
    destroy .dialog_TC
    return $TestValue
}
```

That's a guess, and probably greatly simplified too. But if that's the case, the first event to change the value in the variable (i.e., *most* key-presses in the entry) will cause the `vwait` to stop waiting and trigger the cascade of destruction.

You need to stop waiting on the contents of the entry. You don't want to trigger every time something is altered in it, but rather only when the user says “I'm done and want to make my changes, `OK`” or “I'm done and don't want to make my changes, `Cancel`”. Or, depending on interaction style, “I'm done; my changes are already live. Close this window”. With plenty of experience, the events that you are *actually* needing to listen for are the closing of the window, the press of <kbd>Return</kbd> and the press of <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

Let's fix.

```
proc make-me-a-dialog {}
    global waiting

    toplevel .dialog_TC
    # ...
    add_entry { something ... }
    # ...

    set dlg .dialog_TC
    bind $dlg <Return> [list set waiting($dlg) 1]
    bind $dlg <Escape> [list set waiting($dlg) 0]
    # Trapping a window manager message; slightly different to normal events for historical reasons
    wm protocol $dlg WM_DELETE_WINDOW [list set waiting($dlg) 0]

    vwait waiting($dlg)
    if {waiting($dlg)} {
        return $ValueIndicatingOK
    } else {
        return $ValueIndicatingCancel
    }
}
```

Comment: I have several shortkeys for several tasks. When implementing them, I didn't think of fields where I need to enter text. Combining letters with <Shift> or <Ctrl> will work.

Comment: You can stop dialog-level bindings from firing when the focus is in an entry by putting a `break` at the end of the individual-widget-level binding script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did not think about my shortkeys, that I have also in that script. Whenever one of those letters is written into the entry field the window gets closed. I have to combine keys like ...

```
bind . <Control-Key-a> \
 { tk_messageBox -message "You pressed Control+A" } ;#Control+a
```